# Docusign not changing envelope status from "correct" to 'created', 'sent' or 'delivered' ,after deleting lock of that envelope

Tags: docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts, docusignconnect, docusignapextoolkit

When we call hit envelope lock API of docusign, envelope status gets changed from 'created', 'sent' or 'delivered' to "correct" and when we hit envelope unlock API, ideally it should changed back to 'created', 'sent' or 'delivered'. But sometimes it's not changing it.
I have verified the same with envelope history.

Comment: Please mention endpoints, and code blocks need to solve the issue.

Comment: What do you mean "sometimes" ? it's not consistent behavior?

Answer (score 0):

The [capability to lock/unlock an envelope](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-common-api-tasks-locking-and-unlocking-envelopes) has nothing to do with the envelope's status per-se.

You may use it when you have such need like when someone is correcting an envelope (as the web app is doing) and you want to ensure it's not being modified by someone else at the same time.

However, you will have to separately ensure you set the correct status for the envelope when you do this.